# Why would a "flexibility" option for a flight ticket be only available to the residents of the country where the flight is happens?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, mexico, volaris, mexican-residents

I was looking at some [Volaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volaris) tickets for a flight within Mexico, and read that their "flexibility" option is only available to residents of Mexico. What could explain such a limitation?

[image]

Comment: In the last case, the insurance and assistance is probably the reason for the limitation. In the first case, it might be based on their (current) evaluation of the risk in Mexico (which they can evaluate) compared to other countries (which they don't really want to bother evaluating).

Comment: Could you post the same image in Spanish?

Comment: I can only speculate as to their reasons for doing things, but it seems like this option includes elements of an insurance product rather than just a flexible ticket. Insurance is heavily regulated by many countries; perhaps they believe this lowers their risk of being treated as an unlicensed seller of insurance by regulators in other countries or US states.

Comment: What do the terms and conditions say about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answer that this question received in the comment section: the residency limitation is likely to stem from the fact that the option contains some insurance element.

---

> - In the last case, the insurance and assistance is probably the reason for the limitation. In the first case, it might be based on their (current) evaluation of the risk in Mexico (which they can evaluate) compared to other countries (which they don't really want to bother evaluating). - jcaron
> - I can only speculate as to their reasons for doing things, but it seems like this option includes elements of an insurance product rather than just a flexible ticket. Insurance is heavily regulated by many countries; perhaps they believe this lowers their risk of being treated as an unlicensed seller of insurance by regulators in other countries or US states. Zach Lipton